# Mutual information between two Bernoulli variables

Tags: information-theory

Can we say anything about the mutual information between two Bernoulli variables, $X \sim Bern(p_1)$ and $Y \sim Bern(p_2)$?

And what if $p_1 =1$?

I went as far as
$$I(X;Y) = H(X)-H(X|Y)=-H(X|Y)$$.

Can we do anything more? What if we assume that Y is dependent on X?

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are using for mutual information is slightly wrong (wrong sign), actually $I(X;Y) = H(X) - H(X | Y)$.

If the distribution followed by $X$ is Bern($p_1$), where $p_1 = 1$, then $H(X) = 0$. Consequently, $I(X; Y) = H(X) - H(X | Y) \leq H(X) = 0$.

Edit:

Also, $I(X; Y) \geq 0$ (mutual information can't take on negative values) which, combined with the result above implies $I(X;Y) = 0$.

Comment: Corrected, thanks! Do you think we say anything more about $H(X|Y)$?

Comment: See edit. Mutual information can't take on negative values so in this case mutual information is $0$.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. Btw. why do you say, $I(X; Y) \leq H(X)$?

Comment: Shanon entropy is always positive so $H(X|Y) \geq 0$, implying that $I(X;Y) \leq H(X)$